# Daisy chaining a Harbinger 8 channel compact mixer

Tags: performing, live

Can I daisy chain a Harbinger 8 Channel compact mixer to a Behringer XENYX -1202FX so I can get 
More channels?

Comment: Almost certainly. What seems to be the problem that you are having?

Answer (score 3):

You can run the output of any mixer into a channel (or bus) of another.  What you CAN'T do, unless the mixers are specifically designed to be linked, is share the same effects sends, monitor sends etc.   So think of it as feeding in a submix, not so much as extending the desk.